# How to reset div once content is loaded using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This works fine except I want the `loading-indicator` div to show up when I select a new value from the dropdown. The first time it runs, the loading indicator appears then disappears once the remote content is loaded. I go change the dropdown menu to a different value, but the loading indicator doesn't re-appear. The "new" content eventually shows up once it finishes loading.

```
<select name="branch_name" id="branch_name">
    <option value="Branch1">Branch1</option>
    <option value="Branch2">Branch2</option>
    <option value="Branch3">Branch3</option>
</select>

<div id="mycontent">
    <div id="loading-indicator" style="display:none">
    Scanning subversion<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#branch_name').bind("change", function() {
            $('#loading-indicator').show();
            $('#mycontent').load('/tags/runme',{branch_name: $(this).val()});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using `.bind` and not `.on`? It's the preferred method.

Comment: Yea, it's supposed to be `.on`. I was copying code between two files and forgot to modify that portion when I started this thread. It actually is `.on`. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.load()` *replaces* the element's HTML, so move the loading indicator outside of `#mycontent`, and hide it manually.

```
<div id="loading-indicator" style="display:none">
    Scanning subversion<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
<div id="mycontent"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var $spinner = $('#loading-indicator');
        $('#branch_name').bind("change", function() {
            $spinner.show();
            $('#mycontent').load('/tags/runme',{branch_name: $(this).val()}, function () {
                $spinner.hide();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work properly. I select "Branch1" and I see the spinner. It finishes loading but there's no content. Once I select a different value from the dropdown, then the previous results show up. I believe the `div` up top are mixed up.

Comment: ALMOST there. Spinner is working, now how the heck do I reset the `#mycontent` div? It shows the previous results (along w/ the spinner above it), I would like it to clear out if the dropdown changes.

Comment: Think I got it, I added `$(#mycontent").empty();` before initializing the spinner in the `.on` change portion of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback like this:

```
$('#mycontent').load('/tags/runme',{branch_name: $(this).val()}, function(data) {
   //Do your stuff here, this will be executed once the request is over.
   $('#loading-indicator').hide()
});
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

The loading indicator is inside the div that you are loading with content. Your loaded content replaces everything in that div, including the indicator.

To fix, move the indicator outside the div:

```
<div id="loading-indicator" style="display:none">
<div id="mycontent">
    Scanning subversion<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
</div>
```

or `.prepend()` it after loading the content.

```
$("#mycontent").prepend('<div id="loading-indicator">');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.not()` to exclude your loading indicator.

```
$("#mycontent > div").not('#loading-indicator').hide();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomer123/7rGS2/)